# Click event for newly added menu item

Tags: c#, wpf, events, menuitem

I have a menu item to which I add another item. Now I want to assign click event to that newly added item. How could I do this? Below is how I add menu item.

```
MI.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(ofd.FileName));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a new instance of `MenuItem` class and subscribe to the `Click` event:

```
MenuItem newMenuItem = new MenuItem();
newMenuItem.Header = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(ofd.FileName);
newMenuItem.Click += MenuItemOnClick; // The handler.
MI.Items.Add(newMenuItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcollection.add.aspx) returns an integer indicating the index of the item added, you can then access the element of the collection using this index and therefore subscribe to an event, so you would have to do something like this:

```
var index = MI.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(ofd.FileName));
((UIElement)MI.Items.GetItemAt(index)).MouseLeftButtonUp += OnMenuItemMouseUp;

void OnMenuItemMouseUp (object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the `MenuItem` by its index and attach the event handler using the `+=` syntax:

```
int itemIndex = MI.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(ofd.FileName));
MenuItem item = MI.Items[itemIndex] as MenuItem;
item.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(Item_Click);
```